# AWS S3 , LARAVEL I Next Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception: Error executing "PutObject"

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload images to aws s3, with laravel 7.30, everything is fine when the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is on: ```sync``

when  `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is on `database`  it does not work, in table failed_jobs in the job table I see this error

`I Next Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception: Error executing "PutObject"`

Help me please ...

Comment: This is a permission issue can you check Bucket permissions

Answer (score 0):

this is a permission issue try this
remove line

> 'ACL' => 'public-read'

default permission with list, read, and write but without permission for change object specific permission (PutObjectAcl in AWS policy).